# Calculus involving Integrals

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

Prove that $$\int_0^{\sinh(x)} \sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt =x/2+(\cosh⁡(x)+\sinh⁡(x))/2$$

I am lack of trigonometric properties so if you are so kind to provide me some to be able to solve this equation. I would be thankful.

Comment: That could be integrated by parts, although it'd be quite messy.  And I'm not sure how easily the RHS will fall out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is clearly wrong, since for $x=0$ the LHS vanishes while the RHS
becomes $\frac{1}{2}$. Write $t=\sinh u$ so $dt=\cosh u du$ and the integral is $\int_0^x \cosh^2 u du=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x (1+\cosh 2u)du=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sinh 2x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the substitution:
$$t=\sinh u,\quad \mathrm dt=\cosh u\, \mathrm du.$$
You'll obtain $$\int_0^{\sinh(x)} \sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt =\int_0^x\cosh^2u\,\mathrm du.$$
Then use the linearisation formula:
$$\cosh^2 u=\frac{\cos 2u+1}2.$$